# Stack limit (0.2Gb) exceeded...Probable infinite recursion (cycle):

Tags: recursion, stack, limit, infinite-loop, swi-prolog

Pretty new to Prolog, but I'm trying to implement a context-free grammar and I'm having an issue passing a test case with the rules I have.

I've tried changing the order of my rules to seem more logically correct, but I can't seem to get consistent correct outputs and I continue to get the same stack error. I think it has something to do with `vp --> vp, np.` being recursive, but if that's the case, then why doesn't `np --> np, pp.` give me an error as well? My code is below:

```
:- use_module(library(tabling)).
:- table s/2.

s --> np, vp.
np --> det, n.
np --> np, pp.
vp --> vp, pp.
vp --> v, np.
pp --> p, np.

det --> [the].
n --> [cop].
n --> [criminal].
n --> [street].
v --> [chased].

p --> [in].
p --> [by].
```

Asking this to the query ideally should return **true**:

```
$- s([the,cop,chased,the,criminal], []).
```

And asking this should return **false**:

```
$- s([the, cop, the, criminal, chased], []).
```

I've tried both and they just give me the same error:

```
Stack limit (0.2Gb) exceeded
  Stack sizes: local: 0.2Gb, global: 22Kb, trail: 5Kb
  Stack depth: 1,561,893, last-call: 0%, Choice points: 1,561,869
  Probable infinite recursion (cycle):
    [1,561,893] vp([length:3], _1424)
    [1,561,892] vp([length:3], _1456)
```

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: You use `np --> np, pp`, and `vp --> vp,pp`, so your grammar is *left recursive* (https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg#leftrecursion) which is a problem.

Comment: @anon Please don't summarily delete your questions 30 minutes after someone answers it. it was a good question, and keeping it around allows the answerer to get credit for helping you with their answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have constructed a [*left recursive* grammar](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg#leftrecursion). Indeed if we look at the rules you defined, we see:

```
:- use_module(library(tabling)).
:- table s/2.

s --> np, vp.
np --> det, n.
np --> np, pp.
vp --> vp, pp.
vp --> v, np.
pp --> p, np.

det --> [the].
n --> [cop].
n --> [criminal].
n --> [street].
v --> [chased].

p --> [in].
p --> [by].
```

Now based on how Prolog implements predicates, it can not work with such left recursive grammar, since if you call `np/2`, it will first call `np/2`, and hence we never get out of the "loop" (until the call stack overflows).

We can however use [*tabling*](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/memoization#tabling) here, like you somehow did with `s/2`, which is not necessary, since there is no left-recursive path in `s` that yields (directly or indirectly) `s --> s, ...`. We need to table `np/2` and `vp/2`, like:

```
:- use_module(library(tabling)).
:- table np/2.
:- table vp/2.

s --> np, vp.
np --> det, n.
np --> np, pp.
vp --> vp, pp.
vp --> v, np.
pp --> p, np.

det --> [the].
n --> [cop].
n --> [criminal].
n --> [street].
v --> [chased].

p --> [in].
p --> [by].
```

We then indeed can obtain the expected results:

```
?- s([the,cop,chased,the,criminal], []).
true.

?- s([the, cop, the, criminal, chased], []).
false.
```